# how can I select the exact row (exact number) in sql

Tags: sql, select

I have a problem with select in sql.
Let's say I have a table with columns: ID, hour, temperature(lot of rows).
I want to select EVERY 96 row, determined by the `ID` number.
I mean row number 96, 192, 288 (+96) etc...
Can you help me and give me the right sql statement?

Comment: How do you identify a "Row" in your data? Is it every 96 `ID`? Also which RDBMS are you using (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.)?

Comment: According to which order? And which [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Yes every 96 ID. I am using MySQL.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no effort was made to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you identify a "Row" by it's `ID`, then you can do this by finding the modulus of the `ID` (modulus is the "remainder" after you divide two numbers). If you divide a number by 96 and the modulus is 0, then you have a multiple of 96.

In most RDBMS, the function `MOD()` will do the trick here, although the name of the function and it's parameters may depend on the RDBMS, so caveat emptor:

```
SELECT *
FROM <table>
WHERE MOD(ID,96) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE ID % 96 = 0;
```

Edit:
The % symbol, in almost all languages, is the modulo operator, which when used like a % b, divides a by b and returns the remainder.  As JNevill says, when a % b = 0, then a is a clean multiple of b.

Should also note that a query like this not SARGable will perform poorly on large tables.

Comment: Can you give a bit of context to your answer?